# Spring MVC user data update issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, updating

I’ve an issue with update of user data in Spring MVC app.
So, I have user and I have **FORM** filled with data from **JSP**. Now data from **FORM** overrides all fields of user data with **null**, except entered in **jsp**. 
In another case – user’s data overrides form’s data.
Help me, please, to do it correctly. I’ve tried a lot of variants but nothing works.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView updateView(@ModelAttribute(value = "updateForm")
                                 HttpSession session) {
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    UserForm updateForm = new UserForm();
    updateForm.setUser(user);
    return new ModelAndView("profileupdate", "updateForm", updateForm);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUserProcess(@ModelAttribute(value = "updateForm")
                                    UserForm updateForm,
                                    BindingResult result, Model model,
                                    HttpSession session) {
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        model.addAttribute("updateForm", updateForm);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "profileupdate";
        }

        if (!updatingUser(updateForm, model, user))
            model.addAttribute("errorMsg", "Login or Email is already in use!");
            return "profileupdate";
        }

        return "updated";
    }

    private boolean updatingUser(UserForm updateForm, Model model, User user) {

        fillForm(updateForm, user);
        user = updateForm.getUser();

        //Another case 
        //user = updateForm.getUser();           
        //fillForm(updateForm, user);

        return userService.updateUser(user);
    }
      private void fillForm(UserForm updateForm, User user) {        
      updateForm.setUserId(user.getUserId());          
      updateForm.setLogin(user.getLogin());          
      updateForm.setPassword(user.getPassword());         
      updateForm.setEmail(user.getEmail());  
    }
}
```

** UserForm  class**

```
public class UserForm {
    private Integer userId;
    private String login;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public UserForm() {
    }

    public User getUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(userId);
        user.setLogin(login);
       user.setPassword(password);
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);        
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.userId = user.getUserId();
        this.login = user.getLogin();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.name = user.getName();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
…………………………. 
getters and setters
    }
```

This is my DAO and Service

```
@Override
public boolean updateUser(User user) {
    return userDao.updateUser(user);
}  

@Override
@Transactional
public boolean updateUser(User user) {
    if (isUserExists(user)) {
        return false;
    }
    currentSession().update(user);
    return true;
}
```

**Updade.jsp**

```
<sf:form name="login"
     method="POST"
     action="${app}/edit"
     modelAttribute="updateForm"
     enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

          <label for="login">Login:</label><br>
          <input name="login" id="login" type="text" value=""/> <br>
          <sf:errors path="login" cssClass="error"/><br>

          <br><label for="password">Password:</label>
          <br><input name="password" id="password" type="password" value=""/> 
          <br>
          <sf:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/><br>
          <br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
  </sf:form>
```

Comment: When the controller is falled, is the data in `UserForm` null or the data in `User`?

Comment: Data in User becomes same as data in UserForm. And I want to change only one field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, main problem was in the path on JSP. Instead of handle request through controller I've set just a link to the page. So, advice - be careful and attentive with mappings.

**WRONG VERSION OF LINK**

```
<form name="redaction" 
      action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updatepage.jsp"
      method="GET"
      enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Redaction"/>
 </form>
```

**RIGHT VERSION OF LINK**

```
  <form name="redaction" 
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit"
        method="GET"
        enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Redaction"/>
 </form>
```

And controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateView(UserForm userForm,
                               HttpSession session,
                               ModelMap model) {

        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        userForm.setUser(user);
        model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
        return "profileupdate";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUserProcess(@ModelAttribute(value = "userForm")
                                    UserForm userForm,
                                    BindingResult result, Model model,
                                    HttpSession session) {
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        session.getAttribute("userForm");
        model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
        userValidator.validate(userForm, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            logger.error("Validation error");
            return "profileupdate";
        }
        if (!updatingUser(userForm, model, user)) {     
            logger.error("User update error!");
            logger.error("Login or Email is already in use!");
            model.addAttribute("errorMsg", "Login or Email is already in use!");
            return "profileupdate";
        }
        logger.info("User updated!");
        return "newuserprofile";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be very hard for spring or hibernate to guess what values are null because user wants them to be null and what are null because they do not have to be touched. You as the progammer have to supply a fully completed object.

There are two common ways to do that :

- you suppose null fields should be left untouched and modify `fillform` accordingly :

  ```
  if (updateForm.getUserId().isEmpty()) { updateForm.setUserId(user.getUserId()); }
  ...
  ```
- you prefil your form with current `User` value in the *get* that precedes the *post* (more common unless you need a post without the get part before)

EDIT

To prefill the form (the jsp part seems to be fine) your controller should put a filled `UserForm`in the model in the GET method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String updateView(@ModelAttribute(value = "updateForm")
                                 UserForm updateForm,
                                 HttpSession session) {
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    updateForm.setUser(user);
    return "profileupdate";
}
```

with `updateForm` being implicitely in model due to the `@ModelAttribute` annotation, or

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView updateView(HttpSession session) {
    updateForm = new UserForm();
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    updateForm.setUser(user);
    return new ModelAndView("profileupdate", "updateForm", updateForm);
}
```

I also removed the `value="/edit"` because it is not on `updateUserProcess` and I assumed the `"/edit"` was allready established on controller.

Comment: Oh, I've written not very correctly. I've ment that I want to use second way with prefiling my form with current user. But where I should do it? In GET method?

Comment: Could you show how you display the form ? A JSP, and probably a GET method in you controller ...

Comment: Added. The prolem is - my app doesn't see **updateView(GET)** method at all. This I can see through debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the values of user.getUserID,user.getLogin(),user.getPassword(),user.getEmail()
in the following segment of code? Is it null or the data you recieved in the model object User?

```
      updateForm.setUserId(user.getUserId());          
      updateForm.setLogin(user.getLogin());          
      updateForm.setPassword(user.getPassword());         
      updateForm.setEmail(user.getEmail());
```

Please post the code for  userService.updateUser(user) so that we can understand more.

Comment: I haven't done any cheks becuse I haven't seen it in any examples. Everybody I've asked told me that Hibernate will take care what fields to change.

Comment: Do a check to see if the values are actually getting reflected.